# Difference between unity bootstrappers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, webforms, unity-container

What is the difference between them:

1. Unity.AspNet.WebApi
2. Unity.WebForms
3. Microsoft.Practices.Unity.WebApi

Do I need, i.e. 1 & 2 if I want to use DI in a webforms app with WebAPI ?

Why not just use Microsoft.Practices.Unity, isn't this lib enough to implement D in various scenarios?

**EDIT:**
Why does Unity.WebForms build up the control tree, if you only want to have DI for your IRepository for example?

```
 private void OnPageInitComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (Control controlTree in UnityHttpModule.GetControlTree((Page)sender))
            {
                string fullName = controlTree.GetType().FullName ?? string.Empty;
                string str = (controlTree.GetType().BaseType != null ? controlTree.GetType().BaseType.FullName : string.Empty);
                if (!this.Prefixes.All<string>((string p) => !fullName.StartsWith(p)) || !this.Prefixes.All<string>((string p) => !str.StartsWith(p)))
                {
                    continue;
                }
                UnityContainerExtensions.BuildUp(this.ChildContainer, controlTree.GetType(), controlTree, new ResolverOverride[0]);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only speak for Unity.WebForms, because that is what I wrote and I have not had the time to look at the others yet. The differences between them are most likely around the interception points that each framework supplies. MVC provides the IDependencyResolver interface that allows you to hook into the object creation process. This should be fairly similar for WebAPI (since it shares a lot of code with MVC), but I haven't had the ability to work with WebAPI much recently.

Unlike MVC, WebForms doesn't have an interception point at object creation so we can't do Constructor injection (preferred). The best we can do is Property injection just before execution is transferred to your page. To do that, we walk the control tree looking for controls that have the `[Dependency]` attribute on it (using Unity's `Buildup` method). The latest version of Unity.WebForms allows you to specify namespaces that you want to ignore when performing DI (ignores `System.*` by default) so you can limit it's scope when walking the control tree (very useful when using 3rd-party control libraries like Telerik).

If you are going to use WebForms and WebAPI in the same project, you will probably want to customize them from source to make sure that you are using the same instance of the Unity container. Unity.WebForms places the parent instance of the container in the Application cache and each request gets it's own child container added to the Request items collection.

Hope that helps.